# AutoHotKey FileCopy Error 1

Tags: autohotkey

I am creating AHK script that copy file to startup location but I can't get it to work.

```
#Warn
#NoEnv
appdata := A_AppData
username := A_Username
FileCopy, C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\file.exe, %appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\file.exe
msgbox, 0, lol, %errorlevel%
```

I added temp line `msgbox, 0, lol, %errorlevel%` To see why it's not working. It always show me Error 1.

[image: MsgBox]

I was searching what means error 1 and i found this:

> ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION 1 (0x1) Incorrect function.

Can you help me I dont know what function it means.

Don't ask me why i cant do It manually.

(compiled using default Ahk2Exe convertor)

Sorry if my English is wrong, it's not my natural language.

Comment: Try to [**run the script as administrator**](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm#RunAs), works for me.

Comment: @user3419297 I tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: errorlevel 1 surely does not mean `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION 1 (0x1) Incorrect function.` but something like "error copy  failed". Look it up in the manual @ FileCopy, it'll say how to interpret err 1. Regarding your question, idk sry

Answer (score 0):

Your script seemed to work for me.

I suggest that you use [IfExist](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfExist.htm) to ensure both paths exist, like this:

```
ifnotexist, C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\file.exe
  msgbox, local path isn't correct

ifnotexist, %appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
  msgbox, roaming path is not correct

ifnotexist, %appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\file.exe
  msgbox, file.exe already exists`, please use the overwrite switch
```

If none of msgboxs appear, I'm betting the file in question either is being locked for reading, or some security feature is preventing you from copying the file.